# Developing in C++ using VS Code, is it possible to add a data breakpoint for Visual Studio Windows Debugger?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints

We are developing a native C++ application for Windows, using Visual Studio Code.

From the [documentation of VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug), it seems that the debugger in this scenario is *Visual Studio Windows Debugger*.

From the [documentation of Visual Studio 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022#BKMK_set_a_data_breakpoint_native_cplusplus), it is possible to add a data breakpoint for native C++ development under Visual Studio.

- Is the same *Visual Studio Windows Debugger* also used under Visual Studio (as the name would suggest)?
- Is it possible to add a data breakpoint in VSCode (C++ native Windows development)?

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, it's not supported yet. See [Please implement data breakpoint when using Visual C++ compiled code on Windows #8343](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8343). Give it a thumbs up to show support and increase its prioritization, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like "+1" / "bump".